# Calculating sum in parallel

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

This is an interview question.

N nodes, each node consists of a couple fields and methods. These are:

```
// Every node has an ID. All of these IDs are sequential, and begin with 0.
//   i.e. all ids are uniquely in the range of 0 t N-1
int id;
int val; // Every node has a value
int max; // max = N. Every node knows how many nodes are in the system. 

void send(int idTo, int payload)
int recv(int idFrom)
```

Write a single piece of code which runs on every node simultaneously, such that when it is finished running every node in the system knows the sum of the values of all the nodes in the system.

Comment: Solution which I could think is that on each node, get value from all other node and then add. In this way we will be using both send and recv functions. and all will be running simultaneously.

Comment: The keywords to search for to find solutions are "parallel prefix" "scan algorithm" "recursive doubling"

Comment: Also consider "all reduce" or "global reduction"

Answer (score 5):

You may broadcast your value to every node and receive the values from every other node. 
That way every node will make the addition and will know the result. Though, I think this could be very inefficient.

I like better the idea in the previous answers of receive the partial sum from previous node, add your own value and pass the new sum to the next node. Then you have to transmit the final result in the other direction so every node knows the answer at the end.

But if you want to exploit the fact that all nodes may run simultaniously, you could start the first propagation from both ends and get the final result in the middle, and from there make the second traversal also in both directions. This will save you a half of the time. Better yet, following the same idea, you can make the sum by pairs and send the partial results to the fourth nodes, and then to the eigth, and so on. This strategy will take only O(lg n) to get to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

one solution :

Every node sends the sum it received to the next node in the system. First time every node receives the number from previous node, it notes that down. Next time it receives a number -> it subtracts that number from the previous number and that is the sum.

receive will receive a number from previous node in the system and add its own number to it 
send will send it to the next node in the system
then receive will wait for another input from the previous node

Comment: This take O(N) time, when it can be solved in O(lg N) time as described by ees_cu. At least your solution (if it is what I think it is) only sends O(N) messages, unlike that of @Damien_The_Unbeliever